# Methods to get Holonomic functions

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-functions, algebraic-combinatorics, schur-functions

Let $a_n$ be a holonomic sequence. By definition, that means there exists a linear differential equation of finite order which annihilates $F(x)$, where
$F(x):=\sum a_n x^n$. 
Similarly let $b_n$, $c_n$,$d_n$ be holonomic sequence.

Now we know few methods to get holonomic sequences out of already known holonomic sequences  are as follows

1)$ \textit{Cauchy product}$

$\alpha_n := \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}b_{n-k}$

2) $\textit{Hadamard product}$

$\beta_n = a_n b_n $

I am wondering about the following expression being holonomic.

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}b_{n-k}\sum_{l=0}^{k-1} c_{l}d_{n-l}     $$

It's true special cases of $a_n,b_n$.I wonder if I am missing some tricks.

In particular I want if the series $\gamma_n:=\sum_{k=1}a_k b_{n-k}s_{k,1^{n-k}}$ is holonomic. We obtain the series by taking $c_{l}=s_{(l)}$ and $c_{(d-l)}=s_{1^{d-l}}$. Where $s_{\lambda}$ denote the schur function.

Comment: Why the Schur function tag? In any case, the sequence $n \to s_{n\lambda}(a_1,\dotsc,a_k)$ is holonomic, for any $\lambda$.

Comment: I came up with this identity by playing with hook Schur function along with some polynomial coefficient. $\lambda$ is a partition what you mean by $n\lambda$ ? If $\lambda$ is a hook I know it's holonomic. I am interested to show sequence of the kind $a_n := \sum_{k=1}^{n} s_{\lambda} \prod_{i=1}^{n} G(ih)$ holonomic. In general it will be proven if I could show the identity in my question.

Comment: $n\lambda$ is just elementwise multiplication, that is, make each row n times longer. What type of coefficients do you allow in your case? Symmetric functions, or constants?

Comment: For $a_k,b_k$  you mean? $a_k$ could be symmetric functions  for example $a_k=\prod_{i=1}^{k} (1-ih)^2$ similarliy for $b_k$. Constant will work as well.